# Infinite loop on dispatch with Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm learning React-Toolkit but I've been struggle with this infinite loop.
First of all I'm calling this fetch from:

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getImageProfession(profession.id, region, token));
  }, []);
```

Then in my rootSlice.ts I've:

```
export const getImageProfession = (id: number, region: string, token: string): AppThunk => async(dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch(getImageProfessionsStart());
    const imageData = await getImageProfessionApi(id, region, token);
    dispatch(getImageProfessionsSuccess(imageData));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(getImageProfessionsFailure(err));
  }
};
```

My CreateSlice:

```
export const rootSlice = createSlice({name: 'root',initialState,reducers: {
 getImageProfessionsStart(state) {
  state.loading = true;
},
getImageProfessionsSuccess(state, action: PayloadAction<any>) {
  state.loading = false;
},
getImageProfessionsFailure(state, action: PayloadAction<any>) {
  state.loading = false;
},
```

}

My Endpoint API:

```
export const getImageProfessionApi = async (id: number, region: string, token: string): Promise<any> => {
const namespace = `namespace=static-${region}`;
const locale = 'en_GB';
const { data: responseData } = await axios.get(
    ${link}
  );

  return responseData.assets[0].value;
};
```

And for some reason that I don't understand, calls first getImageProfessionsStart then do the axios get and after that call again getImageProfessionsStart resolving as an inifnite loop.

Most weird thing is that this get it's done like my other gets so I can't find where's the problem.

PD: I know that in my reducer I'm not doing anything with the result of my get (at the moment) but I don't think that that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, was my mistake. I was changing loading state on my reducer. So every time loading goes to false --> true. My component rerenders again so calls again and fetch the same data over and over again.

I fixed it just creating another inistialState loader for my new fetch.

Just FYI...